# Deleting pdf files from a folder if the search word is present using python

Tags: python

Hi i am trying to delete the pdf files in a folder which contains the word "Publications périodiques" in the first , so far i am able to search for the word but dont know how to delete the files .

Code used to search for the word in pdf files

```
import PyPDF2
import re
object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("202105192101394-60.pdf")
String = "Publications périodiques"
for i in range(0, NumPages):
    PageObj = object.getPage(i)
    print("this is page " + str(i)) 
    Text = PageObj.extractText() 
    # print(Text)
    ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
    print(ResSearch)
```

Also how to loop this in multiple files

Comment: You want to iterate through files in a directory perhaps recursively? Use that as search terms, it will turn up lots of results. Add the `[python]` tag to the search above and you're on your way.

Comment: You should not use `object` as a variable name. There is a builtin class called `object`, so when you use it as a variable name, you are hiding that class and you also make it confusing to read your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete any file using:

```
import os
os.remove("C://fake/path/to/file.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a file use

```
import os
os.unlink(file_path)
```

where file_path is the path to the relevant file

Answer (score 0):

For browsing through files:

```py
from os import walk
mypath= "./"
_, _, filenames = next(walk(mypath))
```

Process each file:

```py
for file in filenames:
    foundWord = yourFunction(file)
    if foundWord:
        os.remove(file) # Delete the file
```

Write yourFunction() such that it returns true/false.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your re.search() is already functional? Or is that part of your question?

If functional, you could just use os to get all the files, perhaps filter them through a list comprehension to only get the pdf-files like so:

```
import os

all_files = os.listdir("C:/../or_whatever_path")
only_pdf_files = [file for file in all_files if ".pdf" in file]
```

from that point on, you can iterate through all pdf-files and just execute the same code you've already written for each one and when "ResSearch" is True, delete the File via os.remove() method:

```
for file in only_pdf_files:
   object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
   String = "Publications périodiques"
   for i in range(0, NumPages):
      PageObj = object.getPage(i)
      print("this is page " + str(i))
      Text = PageObj.extractText()
      # print(Text)
      ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
      if ResSearch:
         os.remove(file)
      else:
         pass
```

EDIT:

When your pdf-files aren't in the same directory as your python script, the path is to be added to the `os.remove()` method.

Comment: Hi i am getting an error list index out of range

Comment: This could be the case when you try to change the list INSIDE the loop that is iterating through it. Make sure, that you declare the list that results out of os.listdir() ONLY before iterating through it. If that still doesn't work, do you mind sharing the code you've written so far?

Comment: 'all_files = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\extraction")
only_pdf_files = [file for file in all_files if ".pdf" in file]
for file in only_pdf_files:
   object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
   String = "Publications périodiques"
   for i in range(0, NumPages):
      PageObj = object.getPage(i)
      Text = PageObj.extractText()
      # print(Text)
      ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
      if ResSearch:
         os.remove(file)
      else:
         pass'

Comment: are you sure the error comes from the iteration through `only_pdf_files` ? What does the whole error throw out?

Comment: @ dzat i added a line "NumPages = object.getNumPages()" which solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

```
for file in only_pdf_files:
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
    NumPages = object.getNumPages()
    String = "Publications périodiques"
    for i in range(0, NumPages):
        PageObj = object.getPage(i)
        Text = PageObj.extractText()
        
      # print(Text)
        ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
        if ResSearch:
            os.remove(file)
        else:
            pass
```